# Atlassian Bamboo connecting to SVN over HTTPS

Tags: svn, bamboo

I am evaluating Bamboo as a CI system (currently using Team City)

I am falling at the first hurdle, which is trying to get Bamboo to recognise my repo which is over HTTPS at a third party site (standard username & password auth)

The error given is:

```
This is not a valid Subversion Repository: svn: E175002: Received fatal alert: unexpected_message svn: E175002: OPTIONS request failed
```

TeamCity connects perfectly, running from the same server using the same repo and the same authentication, and I can connect to the repo using HTTPS in the browser

The SVN repo is running 1.6, so I pre-configured that in the Bamboo options (default is 1.7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that the SVN client, used by Bamboo, is trying to issue an HTTP OPTIONS call to the SVN server; it fails, either due to misconfiguration or an authorization issue.

First, determine the user ID used by Bamboo to authenticate against SVN.

Then, inspect your HTTP server's configuration. It's either that the Apache configuration completely disallows HTTP OPTIONS requests, or the execution of HTTP OPTIONS is disallowed for the particular user you're trying to connect with.

Start with looking at the DAV configuration section of your Apache instance.

Answer (score 0):

if i understood correctly your issue, you have to configure svn credentials in bamboo. please follow [1] for that.

1. https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/AOD/Subversion